# Load Electron application from URL

Tags: node.js, electron

I've developed an electron application primarily to to take advantage of been able to use WebViews instead of iframes.

I now have a finished my tool and I would like to be able to launch it from a URL

Is there anyway I can convert my electron app into a web app?

Can I package it and host it on a server that is accessible via a URL?

Any pointers or advice would be great.

Comment: Do you use any electron specific features, like accessing the file system?

Comment: Nope, the only reason I use electron is so I can use the <Webview> tag

Answer (score 0):

> Nope, the only reason I use electron is so I can use the  tag

Than you can just upload your app files to a webserver. You should place your index.html file in the root directory of your webservers html directory so you can just call the url of your domain. If you don't use any electron or node specific features there shouldn't be a problem. Your app will function like a normal web app.

Comment: Only electron or a packaged chrome app can make use off the <webview>  tag, I cant find a workaround. I can host my URL and it does work but the webviews dont load.